# export MaterialModule was not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I have installed Angular Material Library, i was facing Module not found.
May i know any solution for this? Thank you very much.

**material-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
...
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
    exports: [
        A11yModule,
        CdkStepperModule,
        ...
        PortalModule,
        ScrollingModule,
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { MaterialModule } from './library/material-module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    MaterialModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Error Message:**
[image: Angular Material Module Compile Error]

**Version:**
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",

Comment: can you please check the path of material module is proper?

Comment: Material module is your custom module?

Comment: Hi there the path is correct, if not VS Code will get error.

Answer (score 0):

Run **npm install** in terminal and then build and check

Comment: i have try to remove npm folder, clear npm cache before this.

Comment: @Kelvin remove the exports and imports from app module.ts file for materialmodule and try to reinstall them once again this may may work for me it has done